# Why Volatile Static Member Initialization Generate Redefinition Compilation Error?

Tags: c++, static, initialization, volatile, redefinition

My Problem is the following:

I have a class with static counter.
I set this counter as volatile because I use this variable in multithreaded environment.

class.h

```
class myClass
{
 public:
 volatile static int mCounter;
 (...)
};
```

class.cpp

```
int myclass::mCounter = 0;
```

In CPP file, I initialize it, and I obtain the following compilation error:

```
'mCounter' : redefinition; different type modifiers
```

Why ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `volatile` has **nothing** to do with concurrency. Your program is most likely wrong.

Comment: I have dedicated cache for each of my processors, Does the volatile word not ensure that the value will be read from memory and not one of these caches ?

Comment: What is your REAL problem you are trying to solve? Is more than one thread updating `mCounter`? If so, you need more than `volatile`.

Comment: I have more than `volatile`, but my problem was about `volatile`. ;)

Comment: Yes Mats, more than one thread update `mCounter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to repeat the "volatile" on that line as well.

Comment: You mean "it makes no compiler error". I still have the same fear as Kerrek about the correctness of your code.

Comment: Is this code not correct ? (I use mutex to protect each call of mCounter.operator++())

Comment: Right, so do you also use mutexes to protect all the reads? And have you considered using `atomic` instead? It's probably both faster and safer!

Comment: I read this value at the end of my program only, I am not in multithreaded environment anymore at this time, so it is unnecessary in my program. I tried to use `atomics` and `spinlocks`, but both are slower in windows.

Comment: atomics (compiler intrinsics) should be a good deal faster than mutex, since each mutex lock/unlock in itself involves an atomic operation. Try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms683614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx